# Whenever I am using tumblingEventWindow in flink for 30 seconds and using a custom trigger but the trigger is not fired at the registered event time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, eventtrigger, flink-cep

I am using a flink for a tumblingEventOperation and creating a custom trigger to perform operation on it.
My tumbling window code-

```
DataStream<JsonNode> processedWindowedStreamData = filteredData.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new ExtractTimeStamps())
            .keyBy(jsonNode -> jsonNode.get("imei").asText()).window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30)))
            .trigger(new ProcessingTimeCustomTrigger())
            .process(new CollectTripStart());
```

But when I am using a customTrigger upon that to fire it at the customized time i.e. 30 seconds after the first element(event time) but it's been triggered according to the timewindow.getEnd()

```
    public class ProcessingTimeCustomTrigger extends Trigger<JsonNode, TimeWindow> {

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(JsonNode jsonNode, long l, TimeWindow timeWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
        ValueState<Boolean> firstSeen = triggerContext.getPartitionedState(
                new ValueStateDescriptor<>("firstSeen", Types.BOOLEAN));

             // register initial timer only for first element

        System.out.println("The start time is"+timeWindow.getStart());
        System.out.println("The end time is"+timeWindow.getEnd());


        if (firstSeen.value() == null) {
            // FIRE the window 60000 msec after the first event
            long currentProcessingTime = triggerContext.getCurrentProcessingTime();
//            triggerContext.registerProcessingTimeTimer(currentProcessingTime + 60000L);
            long time = l + 30000L;
            System.out.println("The event time is"+time);
            triggerContext.registerEventTimeTimer(time);
            firstSeen.update(true);
                   }
        // Continue. Do not evaluate window now
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long l, TimeWindow timeWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onEventTime(long ts, TimeWindow timeWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Event time is"+ts);
        return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(TimeWindow timeWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Destroying");
        ValueState<Boolean> firstSeen = triggerContext.getPartitionedState(
                new ValueStateDescriptor<>("firstSeen", Types.BOOLEAN));
        firstSeen.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can You tell if You are using somekind of real-life data or just some dummy data ? If so, can You provide the data ?

Comment: real life data...but i can share that the record time are in long format 1606731168000

Comment: So, basically You receive record with the timestamp above and You would expect that to fire at `1606731198000`, but instead it fires somewhere around `1606731180000` ?? Can You also share the code for timestamp extraction ?